# How to create an inverse weight map based on particle system

Tags: particles, weight-painting, instances

I'm creating a forest that consists of trees and grass. After creating a particle system for trees, I want to make the grass appear where there aren't any trees. Instead of creating a new weight paint that manuallly paints spots without trees, is there a faster way of creating a particle system where the grass only appears where there aren't any trees?

Comment: Have you tried inverting the density field in the particle properties ? (The double sided arrow icon on the right of the field)